# Colorbox stopped working after a year of flawless operation (?)

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I added a colorbox to the home page of a client's site, cloverco.com, and it stopped working after about a year. I maintain the site so I know they didn't go in and mess with anything.

The code I used is as follows:

HEAD

```
<!-- Start Coupon Colorbox -->
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.cloverco.com/storage/support/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.cloverco.com/storage/support/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End Coupon Colorbox -->
```

HOME PAGE (before ending body tag):

```
<!-- Start Coupon Colorbox -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$(window).bind('load',
    function(e)
    {
    window.setTimeout(function()
        {
         $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"http://www.cloverco.com/storage/support/colorbox/offer.html"});
        }, /*timeout->*/ 2000);
    });
});
</script>
<!-- End Coupon Colorbox -->
```

The code above is exactly what I used at the beginning and no edits have been made to it since. It worked flawlessly when I added it originally but now does nothing.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're using `jquery-latest`, which means you're blindly updating jQuery. Any breaking changes introduced *(deprecation removals, etc)* may break your code. Start here to track things down: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ Or just use the newest older version that works.

Comment: Great point. Reverted back to 1.8.0 and it works like a dream. Definitely a "why didn't I think of that" moment! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert to the last known version of JQuery that works with colorbox.
On the site it says jquery 1.3.2+ (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) supposing you're using that colorbox. So I suggesting hosting your own jquery. Look up the older versions here and try going down until one works with everything on the site: (http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: I appreciate you and squint's feedback! Worked like a charm!